# Getting errors when validating Symfony2 semantic configuration

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, dependency-injection

I'm trying to write a semantic configuration of the bundle in Symfony2. I have prepared a configuration file using YAML (spu.yml):

```
spu:
    modules:
        spu-module:
            reuqires: []
            path: modules/spu-module.js
```

Then I'm loading it in Extension file (DependencyInjection/spuExtension.php):

```
namespace Gig\SpuBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;


class spuExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration( $configuration, $configs );

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader( $container, new FileLocator( __DIR__ . '/../Resources/config' ) );
        $loader->load( 'services.yml' );
        $loader->load( 'spu.yml' );
    }
}
```

And configuration class ()DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) for this extension is:

```
namespace Gig\SpuBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\ArrayNodeDefinition;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root( 'spu' );

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('modules')
                    ->isRequired()
                    ->prototype('array')
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

When validating the config I get an error:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>   The child node "modules" at path "spu" must be configured.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You must include this in your main app/config/config.yml file

```
imports:
  - { resource: parameters.yml }
  - { resource: security.yml }
  - { resource: spu.yml }
```

If you want to have default parameters, set them in DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
This can be something like this.

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('modules')
            ->isRequired()
            ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()         
            ->prototype('array')
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('reuqires')->end()
                ->scalarNode('path')->defaultValue('modules/spu-module.js')->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end();
```

Comment: But I'm developing a third party bundle and I want it to be installed automatically. Is it necessary? Is there any other way around?

Comment: you may should read the doku about the config component to get a better understanding: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to let the users define the configuration for your bundle in the config.yml file. There is no need for a special file.

You can keep the configuration which you have in your Configuration class but you will have to modify your spuExtension class.

The way Symfony works you will have to read the values from the config.yml for your bundle in the spuExtension class and then set them as parameters. Then you will have easy access to these values by using the container's getParameter method.

This is how your config.yml will look

```
spu:
    modules:
        spu-module:
            reuqires: []
            path: modules/spu-module.js
```

Then in your spuExtension class you can get these values specified by doing:

```
class spuExtension extends Extension
{
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration( $configuration, $configs );

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader( $container, new FileLocator( __DIR__ .     '/../Resources/config' ) );
    $loader->load( 'services.yml' );

    $container->setParameter('modules', $configs[0]);
}
```

}

This will make it easy for you to use the container in an controller to get a parameter.

The $configs variable in the spuExtension will contain all the configuration that is listed under your root. Which in this case is spu.

The way Symfony works you first have to load the configuration in your bundle's extension class and then set this as a parameter, this seems redundant but it's a best practice and it was intended to work like this.

Comment: In my case `$configs[0]` is an empty array

Comment: Have you moved the configuration to the config.yml ?

Comment: No because as far as I know, each bundle should have separate config and I wanted to use semantic configuration and validate params: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html

Comment: As you can see on that same page you linked every configuration should reside in the config.yml file. That file has different namespaces which would include yours (spu). This is just how Symfony works, I don't really get why each bundle should have a seperate config file, since I don't see that listed on that page at all.

Comment: Well, you load config by using Loader class like: `Loader\YamlFileLoader` and that works perfectly fine. The only thing I can't get working is config validation. Loading bundle's config is working correctly. I don't have to mess up in app's config.yml file.

Comment: I presume that you want the user to be able to edit these configurations, right? If not there would be no reason for a seperate configuration file. If you do then it's best to put it into config.yml since if you do it like that the user should create another spu.yml but your loader will not load this.

Long story short, if you want the user to be able to override these configurations just use config.yml since that is how it should work. If an external user shouldn't be able to edit these configurations then why would you even want those configurations?

Comment: @Moshikaro is absolutly right, sunpietro you may dont understand the benefits of the config component, please read the doku about the component

Comment: But why should I have enourmous one config file in the app's directory when I can have few smaller configs for each bundle separately? It's much easier to maintain configs then.

Comment: If you have 100 bundles you would have to have 100 seperate configuration files. It's way easier to just keep track of one configuration file also because the user should override.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it different way.

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader( $container, new FileLocator( __DIR__ . '/../Resources/config' ) );
    $loader->load( 'services.yml' );
    $loader->load( 'spu.yml' );

    $spuConfig  = Yaml::parse(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config/spu.yml');
    $configs    = array_merge($configs, $spuConfig);

    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration( $configuration, $configs );
}
```

And now I'm getting what I wanted. I can validate params in `Configuration` class.